# Кто может объяснить как работает данный слушатель

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase

Как слушатель читает данные из child(receiverRoom), тогда как он установлен только на child (senderRoom), он же не является дочерним элементом child(receiverRoom). Почему DataSnaphot выходит за границы своего родителя ?

```
   val senderRoom = currentUser + " + " + receiverId
    val receiverRoom = receiverId + " + " + currentUser
binding.send.setOnClickListener {
        val message = HashMap<String, Any>()
        message.put("message", binding.editMessage.text.toString())
        message.put("userId", currentUser)
        message.put("time", (Date().time))
        binding.editMessage.setText("")

        database.child(senderRoom).push()
            .setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener {
                database.child(receiverRoom).push()
                    .setValue(message)
            }
    }


    listMessage = ArrayList()
     database.child(senderRoom).addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener{
         override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
             listMessage.clear()
             for(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                 val chats = dataSnapshot.getValue(ChatsModel::class.java)
                 chats?.key = dataSnapshot.key!!
                 listMessage.add(chats!!)
                 adapter.setList(listMessage)


             }
         }
         override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
             Toast.makeText(this@ChatDetail, "Ошибка", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
         }


     })
```

Comment: насколько я вижу вы сетите и туда и туда одно и то же значение, так что читает он из `senderRoom` как и положено

Comment: @DaniilLoban Но когда я меняю текст в receiverRoom он меняется на экране приложения

Comment: это ничего не меняет, тем более я не совсем знаю что у Вас на экране)

Comment: если данные в коллекциях идентичны, как Вы определяете что `слушатель читает данные из child(receiverRoom)`  а не из `child(senderRoom)` ?

Comment: @DaniilLoban потому что когда я удаляю child(receiverRoom) на стороне получателя ничего не выводится на экран, это код для входящих и исходящих сообщений

Comment: Я думаю что этот вопрос стоит доработать, **опишите ожидаемое поведение и то что происходит сейчас, с учетом сторон получателя и отправителя**. На данный момент я вижу что коллекции идентичны (даже встает вопрос зачем их две) и соотвественно визуально их никак нельзя отличить не зная из какого источника идут данные. Данные снапшота идут из той колекции на которую добавлен слушатель.

Comment: @DaniilLoban Все дело в значении которое я передал в переменную (senderRoom)                                val senderRoom = currentUser + " + " + receiverId, когда я его меняю на простой текст то все работает как надо, непонятно как это влияет на слушатель действий. currentUser - это uid текущего пользователя, а receiverId - uid получателя сообщения

Comment: что значит простой текст, приведите конкретные примеры, не очень понятно, но Вы же понимаете что данные не могут влиять настолько на поведение?

Comment: @DaniilLoban val senderRoom = "Текст" когда передаю такое значение в переменную все срабатывает

Comment: @DaniilLoban В том то и дело что понимаю, от этого я еще в большем недоумении

Comment: а зачем Вы используете `+` тут `currentUser + " + " + receiverId` попробуйте как-то иначе например через подчеркивание `currentUser + "_" + receiverId` к тому же пробелы, возможно это как-то влияет на firebase, он воспринимает это как комманду поменять там и там к примеру (не проверял, но думаю лучше избегать таких экзотических имен)

Comment: обычно если решение долго не находится это свидетельствует о том что ищут либо не там либо не так.

Comment: *"когда я удаляю child(receiverRoom) на стороне получателя ничего не выводится на экран"* - правильно, вы подписываетесь на отправленные (`senderRoom`), но получатель ничего не отправлял - поэтому у него и пусто. Вам нужно слушать обе коллекции и как-то согласовывать их в один список на экране, либо исходящие и входящие хранить в одной коллекции, а направление определять по полям отправителя и адресата, указанным в самом сообщении.